# 複数のscopeの結果をひとつにまとめる方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

railsのあるmodelで複数のscopeを使いオブジェクトの並べ方を定義しています。

```
scope :scope_A, -> { where(...).order('created_at DESC') }
scope :scope_B, -> { ......... }
scope :scope_C, -> { ........ }
```

この３つのscope結果を上から順番に取り出して結合した結果を得るにはどうすればいいのでしょうか？
例えばscope_A の結果が `A1,A2,A3`
scope_B の結果が `B1,B2,B3`
scope_C の結果が `C1,C2,C3` とすると
結合結果が `A1,A2,A3,B1,B2,B3,C1,C2,C3` のように並べたいと考えています。

Comment: order は絞り込みではないので、
scope_A => `A1, A2, A3` のとき、scope_B が `B1, B2, B3` になることが理解できません。
where ではないのでしょうか？

Comment: そうですね。実際にはwhereとorderにしています。ご指摘ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQLのように行番号（ここでは ROW_NUMBER）が簡単に取れるRDBMSを使うことが前提ですが、こんなふうに実装するのはどうでしょうか？

```ruby
class Language
  scope :ruby, ->{ where(lang_type: :ruby).order(:id) }
  scope :perl, ->{ where(lang_type: :perl).order(:id) }
  scope :java, ->{ where(lang_type: :java).order(:id) }

  def self.order_by_lang_type
    full_sql = %w(ruby perl java).map.with_index {|type, i|
      sql = self.send(type).select("#{i} AS type_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS row_no, languages.*").to_sql
      "SELECT * FROM (#{sql}) AS t_#{i}"
    }.join(" UNION ALL ") + " ORDER BY type_no, row_no"

    self.find_by_sql(full_sql)
  end
end
```

参考にしたページはこのあたりです。

- [Rails - ActiveRecordでunion使いたい - Qiita](http://qiita.com/kwgch/items/11d88d50bdfb183d6207)
- [ms access - SQL Query - Using Order By in UNION - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213851/sql-query-using-order-by-in-union)

がんばればscopeにもできるようです。

```ruby
scope :order_by_lang_type, -> {
  full_sql = %w(ruby perl java).map.with_index {|type, i|
    sql = self.send(type).select("#{i} AS type_no, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS row_no, languages.*").to_sql
    "SELECT * FROM (#{sql}) AS t_#{i}"
  }.join(" UNION ALL ")

  select("t.*").from(Arel.sql("(#{full_sql}) as t")).order('t.type_no, t.row_no')
}
```

参考ページ： [ruby on rails - Turn SQL query into ActiveRecord Relation - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16324305/turn-sql-query-into-activerecord-relation)

とはいえ件数が少なければ単純に "+" で連結するのありかもしれません。

```ruby
def self.order_by_lang_type
  ruby + perl + java
end
```

Comment: 前回に引き続き、ありがとうございます！！